# Hausdorff decomposition of a measure

Tags: measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb R^n,\mathcal B^n)$. Is it true that $\mu$ can be decomposed as a countable sum of measures which are only distributed on sets of a fixed Hausdorff dimension?
$$$$
In formal terms that
$$\forall A\in \mathcal B^n,\ \ \  \mu(A)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu_{a_k}(A)$$
s.t. for all k
$$\exists E,\ dim_H(E)=a_k:\ \ \mu_{a_k}(\mathbb R^n-E)=0$$
$$\forall F,\ dim_H(F)<a_k:\ \ \mu_{a_k}(F)=0$$
Note that the result trivially holds for all continue probability distributions and for all discrete ones. I cannot imagine a probability measure $\mu$ such that it does not hold and since it is rather interesting and useful I wonder if it plays a role in some branch of measure theory.